# Azure UserDelegation Key Exception

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to generate UserDelegationKey for my Azure Storage Blob but i am getting an exception:

> Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource (unrecognized type)

This Exception occurs when i call getUserDelegationKey on BlobContainerAsyncClient

Version of my azure-storage-blob library is 12.12.0
Below is the code snippet

```
 private void uploadNextWeekReportToAzure() {
    BlobServiceAsyncClient blobServiceAsyncClient = blobServiceClientBuilder
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildAsyncClient();
    BlobContainerAsyncClient blobContainerAsyncClient = blobServiceAsyncClient.getBlobContainerAsyncClient("container name");
    BlobAsyncClient blobAsyncClient = blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient("blob name");
    OffsetDateTime keyStart = OffsetDateTime.now();
    OffsetDateTime keyExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(7);
    blobServiceAsyncClient.getUserDelegationKey(keyStart,keyExpiry)
    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Exception occurred:{}",throwable.getMessage()))
    .doOnSuccess(userDelegationKey -> {
      log.info("UserDelegationKey:{}",userDelegationKey.getValue());
      String saSToken = generateSaSToken(blobAsyncClient, userDelegationKey);
      log.info("SAS TOKEN:{}",saSToken);
    })
    .subscribe();
  }

private String generateSaSToken(BlobAsyncClient blobAsyncClient,
                                  UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey) {
    BlobContainerSasPermission blobContainerSasPermission = new BlobContainerSasPermission()
        .setReadPermission(true);
    BlobServiceSasSignatureValues builder = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(
        OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1), blobContainerSasPermission)
        .setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY);
    return String
        .format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s?%s", blobAsyncClient.getAccountName(),
            blobAsyncClient.getContainerName(),
            blobAsyncClient.getBlobName(),
            blobAsyncClient.generateUserDelegationSas(builder, userDelegationKey));
  }
```

Complete Exception Trace:

> CallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource (unrecognized type)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not instantiate Stax reader for XML source type class org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource (unrecognized type)
> at io.strati.libs.forklift.com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:770)
> at io.strati.libs.forklift.com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:345)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:631)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:29)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1124)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3643)
> at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.deserialize(JacksonAdapter.java:281)
> at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseBodyDecoder.deserializeBody(HttpResponseBodyDecoder.java:169)
> at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseBodyDecoder.lambda$decodeByteArray$1(HttpResponseBodyDecoder.java:105)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:143)
> at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:188)
> at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
> at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:179)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:284)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
> at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:173)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2663)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:145)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:212)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269)
> at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:401)
> at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:416)
> at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:470)
> at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:685)
> at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94)

Comment: FYI i have already set the AZURE_TENANT_ID,AZURE_CLIENT_ID,AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
as env variables

Comment: Update: I fixed this issue by removing jackson dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to generate user delegation key and SAS

```
String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", "accountName");,
blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()).buildClient();
keyStart = OffsetDateTime.now();
keyExpiry = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(7);
userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(keyStart, keyExpiry);
BlobContainerSasPermission blobContainerSas = new BlobContainerSasPermission();
blobContainerSas.setReadPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues blobServiceSasSignatureValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(keyExpiry,blobContainerSas);
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient=blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("containerName");
if (!blobContainerClient.exists())
    blobContainerClient.create();
String sas = blobContainerClient.generateUserDelegationSas(blobServiceSasSignatureValues, userDelegationKey);
```

For more information refer  this [link](http://5.9.10.113/64242397/azure-sdk-for-java-how-to-setup-user-delegation-key-and-shared-authentication-si)

You may also check this method to Generate Key

The Get User Delegation Key operation gets a key that can be used to sign a user delegation SAS (shared access signature). A user delegation SAS grants access to resources in the Blob service using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) credentials.

For more information refer  this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest)